# Encuestas con "Shinysurveys"

Tags: r, shiny

Necesito su ayuda. Quiero hacer una encuesta con "shinysurvey". Allí pueden ver una plantilla básica. No puedo hacer que cuando presione "submit", agregar la fila a un dataframe. significa que, si presiono tres veces el botón de submit, quiero que agregue[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]a tres filas. Probé con la función "getSurveyData", pero solo imprime la última fila.
¡Muchas gracias!

[image: codigo1]
[![codigo2`library(shiny)
library(shinysurveys)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#######################################################################

##########################################################################

## Define questions in the format of a shinysurvey

survey_questions <- data.frame(
question = c("What is your favorite food?",
"What's your name?"),
option = NA,
input_type = "text",
input_id = c("favorite_food", "name"),
dependence = NA,
dependence_value = NA,
required = c(TRUE, FALSE)
)

## Define shiny UI

ui <- fluidPage(
surveyOutput(survey_questions,
survey_title = "Hello, World!",
survey_description = "A demo survey"),
fluidRow( column( 7, dataTableOutput("tabla_sal") ),
column(2, htmlOutput("text") ) ),

)

## Define shiny server

server <- function(input, output, session) {
renderSurvey()
#######################################################################

counter <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 0) # Defining & initializing the reactiveValues object

observeEvent( input$submit, {
counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue + 1     # if the add button is clicked, increment the value by 1 and update it

}) #Cierra el observeEvent

```
####################################################################
```

output$text <- renderText( {
HTML(paste(sprintf("You have chosen: %s", counter$countervalue)))

})

```
# RESUMEN GENERAL. POSICIÓN TODAS
```

tablageneral<- reactive({

```
j<- counter$countervalue

print(j)

if(j==0){

mitabla<-getSurveyData(custom_id = "test")

} else {
 
   mitabla<- union( mitabla, getSurveyData(custom_id = "test") )
  
   }

print(nrow(mitabla))
mitabla
```

})

output$tabla_sal <- renderDataTable({

```
tablageneral()
```

}
)

}

## Run the shiny application

shinyApp(ui, server)
`][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBU6O.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBU6O.png)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas usando mal el package. Mira los ejemplos que trae:
shinysurveys::demo_survey() y
shinysurveys::demo_survey_multipage()

La base de todo esta en un dataframe que contiene las preguntas que quieres usar en tu encuesta. Dependiendo del tipo de pregunta y respuesta que requieras vas definiendo cada uno en la columna input_type.

La funcionalidad que describes me parece que se acerca mas a la demo_suvey_multipage por lo que recomendaria que le des un vistazo.

Espero te sirva.

saludos!